# SQLAlchemy - Combine Textual query with a filter

Tags: python, string, text, filter, sqlalchemy

I'm using **SA 0.6.6**, **Python 2.66** and **Postgres 8.3**.

I have certain queries which require somewhat complex security check that can be handled with a `WITH RECURSIVE` query.  What I'm trying to do is combine a textual query with a query object so I can apply filters as necessary.

My original thought was was to create my text query as a subquery and then combine that with the user's query and filters.  Unfortunately, this isn't working.

```
subquery = session.query(sharedFilterAlias).\
                   from_statement(sharedFilterQuery).subquery()
```

This results in this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Annotated_TextClause' object has no attribute 'alias'
```

Is there anyway to combine a textual query with SQLAlchemy's query object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a time going by without an answer [I posted to the SA Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/VAttoxkLlXw), where [Michael Bayer](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/) himself set me in the right direction.

The answer is to turn my text query into an SA text clause.  Then use that with in_ operator.  Here's an example of the finished product:

```
sharedFilterQuery = '''WITH    RECURSIVE
        q AS
        (
        SELECT  h.*
        FROM    "Selection"."FilterFolder" h
        join "Selection"."Filter" f
        on f."filterFolderId" = h.id
        WHERE   f.id = :filterId 
        UNION
        SELECT  hp.*
        FROM    q
        JOIN    "Selection"."FilterFolder" hp
        ON      hp.id = q."parentFolderId"
        )
SELECT  f.id
FROM    "Selection"."Filter" f
where f.id = :filterId and
(f."createdByUserId" = 1 or
exists(select 1 from q where "isShared" = TRUE LIMIT 1))
'''

inClause = text(sharedFilterQuery,bindparams=[bindparam('filterId',filterId)])

f = session.query(Filter)\
.filter(Filter.description == None)\
.filter(Filter.id.in_(inClause)).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had luck with subqueries chaining the [select_from](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/expressions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.select_from) method to query method. Something like this might work; but not knowing more about your data models and the SQL you're trying to generate I cannot be certain.

```
results = session.query(sharedFilterAlias).select_from(sharedFilterQuery).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Philip, but select_from accepts a mapped entity, or FromClause objects, not text.  My data model is not really relevant to the question of how to combine a text query with filters.