# SQLAlchemy filtering using SQL statement

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a simple ORM in SQLAlchemy that retrieves a table from a SQL Server. Some columns of this table have T-SQL statements that I must execute as a filter parameter in order to filter the other query.

```
subquery = session.query(OtherModel).all().subquery()

r = session
.query(MyModel)
.join(subQuery,and_(MyModel.datecolumn >= subquery.c.sqlcode ))
```

Or doing directly:

```
r = session
.query(MyModel)
.join(subQuery,and_(MyModel.datecolumn >= 'CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)' ))
```

My expected result is to inject some SQL code inside the query that I'll be executed but instead I'm receiving a "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

This is happening because my code is being enclosed by apostrophes but I don't want this behaviour.

Is there a way to force SQLAlchemy to understand my parameter as a SQL code instead of a String ?

UPDATE:

Apparently, it's not possible to deal with that without text clauses.
The problem I was trying to address is similar to this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy import text,and_

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Address(email_address='%s')>" % self.email_address

User.addresses = relationship("Address", order_by=Address.id, back_populates="user")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()


    fake_user = User(name='fakeuser', fullname='Invalid', nickname='12345')
    session.add(fake_user)

    jack = User(name='jack', fullname='Jack Bean', nickname='gjffdd')
    jack.addresses = [Address(email_address='jack@google.com'),Address(email_address='jack@google.com'),]
    session.add(jack)

    session.commit()

    stmt = session.query(Address.user_id, func.count('*').label('address_count')).group_by(Address.user_id).subquery()

    q = session.query(User, stmt.c.address_count).outerjoin(stmt,and_(
        User.id == stmt.c.user_id,
        text(" users.id >= SOMEDATABASEFUNCTION(:x) ").bindparams(x=stmt.c.user_id)
    )).order_by(User.id)

    print(q.statement)
```

Where the SOMEDATABASEFUNCTION is a function from my SQL Server database.

I'm using other approach using full textual queries similar to this:

[SQLAlchemy - Combine Textual query with a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472501/sqlalchemy-combine-textual-query-with-a-filter)

Comment: [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text)?

Comment: Apparently, it's not possible without specifying a full textual sql clause to deal with that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472501/sqlalchemy-combine-textual-query-with-a-filter

Comment: In my testing, `r = session.query(MyModel).join(subquery, and_(MyModel.datecolumn >= text('CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)'))).all()` renders `SELECT mymodel.id AS mymodel_id, mymodel.datecolumn AS mymodel_datecolumn 
FROM mymodel INNER JOIN (SELECT othermodel.id AS id
FROM othermodel) AS anon_1 ON mymodel.datecolumn >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`