# How to add "AND EXISTS (SELECT ...)" to a Python/SqlAlchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SqlAlchemy query that looks like this.

```
results = (
    session.query(MyFirstTable)
    # various .join() and .filter() removed for brevity.
    .all()
)
```

I want to add another `.filter`, but if I were writing SQL, it would look like:

```
SELECT * MyFirstTable
    -- INNER JOINs and WHEREs removed for brevity.
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable
            WHERE MyFirstTable.ID = MyOtherTable.myFirstTableID
            AND MyOtherTable.OtherThing = 42
    )
```

I want the top level query to only return a record of `MyFirstTable`, if that record matches its primary key (`ID`) with one in another in another table (`MyOtherTable`) AND that record in the other table matches other conditions.

(Note that the other table might have several records that match this second WHERE. I only care if that number is zero or not-zero.)

Is there a way to write a `.filter()` to add onto the chain just before the final `.all()` that will do this?

Comment: Would something like the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472501/sqlalchemy-combine-textual-query-with-a-filter work for you?

Comment: You can get the same effect by joining with a subquery that returns `DISTINCT MyOtherTable.myFirstTableID`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by placing the "exists" subquery inside the filter and then calling its [exists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.exists) method, like this:

```py
with Session() as s:
    subq1 = s.query().filter(
        sa.and_(FirstTable.id == OtherTable.id, OtherTable.other_thing == 42)
    )
    stmt1 = s.query(FirstTable).filter(subq1.exists())
    for ft in stmt1:
        print(f'{ft.id=}')
```

Generating this SQL:

```sql
SELECT t1.id AS t1_id 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.other_thing = ?)
```

The SQLAlchemy 2-style `select` is structurally identical ([exists tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#exists-subqueries)):

```py
with Session(engine) as s:
    subq2 = sa.select(1).where(
        sa.and_(FirstTable.id == OtherTable.id, OtherTable.other_thing == 42)
    )
    stmt2 = sa.select(FirstTable).where(subq2.exists())
```